# HTML5 audio stuttering, how to debug Pulseaudio?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

i've got a strange issue with audio playback on html5 videos (youtube for example).

The Video plays fine, but the sound has dropouts for about 1 second almost every minute. Is there a way to debug this?

Soundcloud and Spotify (native app) have no dropouts, I've tested Google Chrome and Iceweasel, same behavior.

Thanks in advance,
Lybs

System: 
Linux lybs-think 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux - up2date
running Cinnamon 2.2.16